# Laptop shut off randomly and wont turn back on

Tags: boot, battery

As the title says I have a laptop that has been working perfectly fine. Today I was watching a youtube video and the laptop suddenly turned off (I was at around 75% battery) and now it wont turn back on. Ive tried plugging it in and everthing but when I press the power button I can hear the fan spin for a second before stopping. What should I do

Comment: You can try plugging it in and taking the battery out and powering it up without it. Then later power it off normally, put the battery back in and see if it boots ok.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix unfortunately my laptop is designed so that I would have to disassemble the whole casing and keyboard to get the battery out. Hopefully I wont have to resort to that

Comment: There is a bug where a certain percentage of battery life confuses the OS into thinking it should shut down immediately. You can search on that to see if there is a fix. In the meantime you can simply boot your laptop, go to the BIOS setup screen and leave it there to drain the battery. Then plug in the laptop and boot it again. Never had the problem personally, only read about problems others have had... Just occurred to me also let it charge to 100% and then turn it on. DUH. Should have thought of that first place. In either case, after you are up and running, you can tweak the power setting